# Calculate determinant of $n \times n$ depending on n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

My task is to figure out determinant of following matrix depending on $n$.  I want to solve it without altering the rows!
$$
A^{n,n} = \begin{vmatrix} 
0  &    & ... & 0  & -1\\
   &    &     & -1 & 0 \\
   &    & ... &    &   \\
0  & -1 &     &    &   \\
-1 & 0  & ... &    &0  \\
 \end{vmatrix}
$$

This will be $\pm1$ depending on following two things.

1. Multiplication of $-1$. This is simply $-1^n$
2. The number of left-down positions - 1. For $1\times1$ det is simply $(+1)*(-1)$. For $2\times2$ it's $(-1)*(1)$ and so on.

So the rule should look like so:

$$det(A) = -1^n \times -1^{ld_positions - 1}$$

Now the only complicated thing was to figure out the nuber of left-down positions to know the second part. I believe it's $$\sum_{0}^{n-1}n$$ where $n$ is the matrix dimension.

But my solution did not pass my test calculations, so it must be wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the determinant using Laplace's expansion, if you don't want to use row operations.
$$(-1\cdot(-1)^{n-1})\cdot(-1\cdot(-1)^{n-2})\cdot ... \cdot(-1\cdot(-1)^1)\cdot(-1)=(-1)^n \cdot (-1)^{(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1}=(-1)^{n+(n-1)n/2}=(-1)^{(n+1)n/2}$$

Note that this evaluates to $1$, if $n\equiv 0$ or $n\equiv 3$ and to $-1$, if $n\equiv 1$ or $n\equiv 2$. (mod 4)

Answer (score 0):

What about induction?

By Cramers rule you have

$$\det(A^{n\times n}) = (-1)^n \cdot \det(A^{n-1 \times n-1})$$.

Furthermore, we have $\det(A^{1\times 1})=-1$.

Then:
$$\det(A^{n\times n}) = \prod_{i=2}^n (-1)^i \cdot (-1) = (-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^n i} = (-1)^{n(n+1)/2}$$.

Or am I wrong?

Comment: Actually, our answers don't quite match.

Comment: @Alex: that was a typo. I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you swap rows around you can transform this matrix into a diagonal one, the determinant is then the product of the diagonal elements. So we have to multiply $(-1)^n$, the product of the element of the diagonal, with the right power of $-1$ coming for the rows interchanges. To bring the last row to the first position we need $n-1$ swaps, to bring the formerly $(n-1)$-th row to the second position we need $n-2$ swaps and so on, therefore
\begin{equation}
\det A=(-1)^{n-1}\cdot(-1)^{n-2} \cdots\cdot(-1)\cdot(-1)^n
=(-1)^{1+2+\ldots +n}=(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Im glad, you arrive at the same result as me.

Comment: Now we have 3 different ways getting the same result :P

Comment: It's always good to have independent checks :)